# Issue while puling User info through Directory Google API

Tags: google-api, google-apps

I experience an issue while accessing Directory API to get data about a user:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
    "reason" : "accessNotConfigured"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
}.
```

The code I used to access it:

```
    Directory service = (Directory) GoogleClientHelper.getClientOAuth20(Directory.Builder.class, email, null, null);
    Directory.Users.Get request = service.users().get(email);
    User user = request.execute();
```

However, the following code works perfect:

```
        Directory service = (Directory) GoogleClientHelper.getClientOAuth20(Directory.Builder.class, email, null, null);
        Directory.Users.List request = service.users().list().setCustomer(adminAccount);

        do {
            try {
                Users currentPage = request.execute();
                allUsers.addAll(currentPage.getUsers());
                request.setPageToken(currentPage.getNextPageToken());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                request.setPageToken(null);
            }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

Please support.

Thank you,
Evgeny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it looks like your API project on the Developers Console isn't configured correctly (could have the Admin SDK set to 'OFF'). Check [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) under 'Set up your API' for more info.

When you say the following code works perfectly, is it using another API project?